# How to make data column headers sortable?

Tags: sorting, libreoffice-calc

Can anybody explain how to make data table column headers sortable in *LibreOffice Calc* with little up and down buttons at the end of the header cell like in *Excel*?

I am using it on Ubuntu 14, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the **[AutoFilter](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/AutoFilter)** feature:

1. Make sure the columns have headers (otherwise, the first data row will be used as header...)
2. Select Columns
3. Menu `Data` -> `Filter` -> `AutoFilter`.